# Can you document EE tags with EE?

Tags: tags, parse-order, parse

I've run into this before - and have never found a 'great' solution. The crux of my problem is that I need to document some EE tags, using content in a channel entry.

For example, I'd like to output something like:

```
<pre><code>

{exp:someth:ing}

<code><pre>
```

The issue is, that of course, EE htmlentifies the curly brackets, so what I end up with is:

```
<pre><code>

&#123;exp:someth:ing&#125;

<code><pre>
```

I've tried using CE Str (awesome plugin by the way) to decode these html entities, which it does - flawlessly. However, at that point, due to what I'm assuming is a parse order issue - EE then tries to process those tags rather than just outputting them.

In the past, the only solution I have found required including PHP in my templates which is not really an option anymore. I've tried knocking out a quick plugin - but have had no luck.

Any ideas would be wildly appreciated.

I'm hoping there is some magic addon like:

```
{exp:donot:parsetags}
   ...
{/exp:donot:parsetags}
```

But so far, I cannot find it - and maybe I am just searching for the wrong keywords.

MW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw your question, and decided to release an add-on I wrote a few years ago for my own documentation: [CE Highlight](https://bitbucket.org/causingeffect/ce-highlight).

The add-on has the ability to optionally style the output, use line numbers, highlight specific lines, and a few other things. It leverages Geshi for the heavy lifting. I hope that helps!

Comment: Aaron, Jess and Justin - thank you all so much for taking the time to answer. I think all THREE answers will get me exactly what I need, and I'm not sure I can actually mark three as "Correct Answer" - so I am going to mark Aaron's as so, because, well, he released a freakin' addon! Love this community. You all rock and I will buy you each a cocktail the next time we are near a bar at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your code in `[code]{ee_tag_here}[/code]` and that should output `<code>{ee_tag_here}</code>` into your template.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try Template Code from Rob Sanchez for this. Not sure if it still works with latest EE versions, but you might be able to update it.

https://github.com/rsanchez/template_code